# How to get position of first and last position of viewpager?

Tags: android, count, textview

I want to hide left arrow when the first position of a ViewPager and hide right arrow when the last position of a ViewPager. And then , I also want to show current page number with TextView like (5/30). 5 is current page number and 30 is total page number. Thank You Sir.

Here is my code;

```
mPager.beginFakeDrag();
leftNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.left_nav);
rightNav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.right_nav);
txt_count = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.txt);

int tab = mPager.getCurrentItem();
if (tab == 0){
    leftNav.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide all position :(
}

leftNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int tab = mPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (tab > 0) {
            tab--;
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
        } else if (tab == 0) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
        }
    }
});

rightNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int tab = mPager.getCurrentItem();
        tab++;
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onPageChangeListener as shown below

```
 mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                       if (position == (mPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1)) {
                            rightNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       } else {
                            rightNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }

                       if (position == 0) {
                            leftNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       } else {
                            leftNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }
                });
```

Your Click listener for left & right arrow buttons

```
 leftNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPager.getAdapter() != null && mPager.getAdapter().getCount() != null && mPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                }
            }
        });
        rightNav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPager.getAdapter() != null && mPager.getAdapter().getCount() != null && mPager.getCurrentItem() != (mPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1)) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @StevenLin check my edited answer with your left & right arrow buttons click listener

Comment: debug & compare position, does mPager.getAdapter().getCount(); return correct size if not use yourArrayList.size() to get same

Comment: No :D it doesn't happen.. first time left arrow doesn't hide and go next.. right arrow doesn't hide and go back.. left arrow hide and go next... right arrow doesn't hide **mPager.getAdapter().getCount() != null** operator cannot be applied to int

Comment: sorry my mistake, i have changed onPageSelected() code pls compare it

Comment: first time first page left arrow doesn't hide, later go back it hide. why? I change  mPager.getAdapter().getCount() > 0 because != cannot be applied to int

Comment: initially keep both arrow visibility GONE in your xml layout

Comment: @StevenLin will do that for you :)

Comment: @DivyangPanchal not working for me. the right arrow visibility gets gone after clicking one more time on the arrow. any suggestions plzz

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem()

ViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() The getAdapter() method returns the object that supplies the pages for the ViewPager.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all page count in `ViewPager`, use getAdapter method of the [viewPager.getAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getAdapter())

```
viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()
```

To find out current page of `ViewPager` use [ViewPager.getCuurentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem())

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnPageChangeListener`

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(position == 0)
        {
            // hide left nav
        }
        else if(position == mPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) // is last position
        {
            // hide right nav
        }
        else
        {
            // show all nav
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html