# Viewpager detect first and last position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a `viewpager` with left and right arrows.  I want to hide left arrow when the first position of a ViewPager and hide right arrow when the last position of a ViewPager visible.

I have referred this solution: [How to get position of first and last position of viewpager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42060719/8089770)

**In my view pager I have 3 visible pages at a time. For this I have used getPageWidth to 0.33f** :

[image]

But it did not work as expected for me.

My code :

```
vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    if (position == (vpPager.getAdapter().getCount())-1) {
                        right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (position == 0) {
                        left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

In XML I have set visibility gone for both arrows.

Any help will be appreciatable. Thank you!

Comment: One question: how many dots do you want to be displayed?

Comment: No dots are there.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is working fine with me.

#### In order to know last position:

For your case, you cannot get last position '6' from onPageSelected(int position). If you got position **totalNumberofPages - numberOfVisiblePagesAtATime**, last page is already visible on screen.
For eg , 7-3 = 4 (If you got position 4, it means last page position 6 is already on screen.)

#### In order to know first position:

you cannot check in `onPageChangeListener()`. Because this will not call in first time launch.
You need to INVISIBLE your left arrow after `viewPager` setup. Then in `onPageChangeListener` call, VISIBLE again.

Comment: Your second point worked. but at the last page right arrow is not getting invisible.

Comment: Could you debug that ur app know this is last position or not? So we can filter problem source. If ur app know this is last position, ur bug coming from UI. If not, we need to double check again.

Comment: Yeah i am debuging. and i have used get page width fuction in view pager. so it is showing 3 items at a time.

Comment: Yes it is giving correct last position after removing -1. but still it is not invisible,

Comment: In order to know that ur arrow is working, How about you check with GONE or change drawable of this arrow?

Comment: I have checked by log. for last position where i have written visibility gone code i checked log.

Comment: Sorry ~I don't understand what your are trying to say.  I means is to use  right.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I have used viewpager getwidth method which devides pages to 3 at a time. so in this case i am getting position only 0,1,2,3 and my items are 6.

Comment: So, getting position from view pager is not working properly and the rest are working (scrolling, showing page by page etc) ?

Comment: Hi Annie, Sorry for late reply. We were celebrating Lunar new year. If you would like to know "last page is already visible on screen or not", you just need to do is **total number of pages - number of visible pages at a time** , in your case, 7-3=4, if you got position 4, last page (position 6) is already shown on screen. Do let me know if this is you would like to do or not.

Comment: Thank you it worked :) .And a very Happy new year to you !

Comment: Good to hear that, I will update my answer according to this. Thank you Annie.

Answer (score 3):

To find out current page of ViewPager use [ViewPager.getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem())

Here is a code sample

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new CustomViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            int currentItem = vpPager.getCurrentItem();

            if (currentItem == (vpPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1)) {
                right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (currentItem == 0) {
                left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Should I need to invisible arrows in XML?

Comment: At first no arrows are visible.right arrow gets invisible after clicking on one more time after last item.

Comment: In your XML, the right arrow only should be visible, since the first page is selected by default. When your on the last page you should not see the right arrow. Do you ?

Comment: I am not able to see any arrow at beginning. and yes at last page right arrow is still visible.

Comment: Please post your XML file. Are you sure your left and right arrows are pointing to the correct XML element ?

Comment: You don't need to call `vpPager.getCurrentItem();`. The position passed to the callback will have exactly the same value. The rest of the code is identical, so please consider removing this answer.

Comment: @IulianPopescu in position i am getting 0,1 and in vpPager.getCurrentItem() i am getting 0,1,2,3

Comment: @Annie Can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem ?

Comment: @matdev No it is not working for me. As my viewpager is not normal one it has three views at a time. so this will not work. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it work, I would use `onPageScrolled` instead of `onPageSelected` since the later one is not called right after the `ViewPager` is initialised and you can keep the buttons visible in the xml file. It would look like this:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        if (position == 0) {
            left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (position == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
            right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

The next and previous buttons are set to work like this:

```
left.setOnClickListener((v) -> mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true));
right.setOnClickListener((v) -> mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true));
```

Also, using `onPageScrolled` you can create a nice fade-in/fade-out animation for the buttons to stop them from appearing suddenly on the screen.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I have used viewpager getwidth method which devides pages to 3 at a time. so in this case i am getting position only 0,1,2,3 and my items are 6.

Comment: And why exactly are you doing that?

Comment: It's requirement in design

Comment: So you have 3 views that are visible at all times on the screen? Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4RA5.jpg?

Comment: Yes perfect. It looks like this.

Comment: Ok, let me see what's the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int myImagePosition = -1; // class level variable with default value -1.
```

> **set visibility of imageView when user click on next or previous**
>   **buttons.**

```
        myImageViewViewPagerPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (myImagePosition > 0) {
                   myImagePosition = myImagePosition - 3;
                    setNextPreviousArrowVisibility();
                }
                myViewPagerPlanDetailBroucher.setCurrentItem(myImagePosition);
            }
        });

        myImageViewViewPagerNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (myImagePosition < myBroucherDataArrayList.size() - 1) {
                    myImagePosition = myImagePosition + 3;
                    setNextPreviousArrowVisibility();
                }
                myViewPagerPlanDetailBroucher.setCurrentItem(myImagePosition);
            }
        });

        private void setNextPreviousArrowVisibility() {
        if (myImagePosition > 3) {
            myImageViewViewPagerPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            myImageViewViewPagerPrevious.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (myImagePosition > -1 && myImagePosition < myArrayList.size() - 1) {
            myImageViewViewPagerNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            myImageViewViewPagerNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working in my case. The right arrow goes invisible after one more time click on arrow. also i would need this on viewpager scroll. Thank youu for your response.

Comment: check code now, I have made some changes, need to check with more than 3 images